# Actualizacion en el inspector de elementos

Tags: html, css, mediaqueries

Cada vez que abro el inspector de elementos en algunas paginas web lo hace en la misma página lo normal y en otras el inspector se abre en una nueva ventana, lo que no me permite trabajar con los tamaños de pantalla, se que puedo cambiar la forma de desplegarse del inspector mediante la opcion de dock side, el problema que tengo es que cuando el inspector de elementos se abre en una nueva ventana esa opcion no me aparece, como puedo hacer que el inspector se habra en la misma pagina por defecto? o en su defecto como puedo trabajar con los tamaños de pantalla con el inspector abierto en una nueva ventana

Comment: Ninguna de las etiquetas que usaste están realmente relacionadas con la pregunta que, además, no tiene que ver con programación y, seguramente, terminará cerrada. Por cierto, ¿qué navegador estás usando y en qué sistema operativo?

Comment: disculpa por usas algunas etiquetas de mas, realmente no sabia que etiqueta usar correctamente, estoy usando brave y lo que mencionaba pasa con todos los navegadores que usan chromium

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035408/2412893) funciona perfecto.